# sentinel error occurred while executing oct2py in python for running octave script

Tags: python, matlab, octave, sentinel, oct2py

I am trying to use oct2py to run octave script(.m file) in python.
here is the code

```
import os 
os.environ['OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE'] = ('C:\\Program Files\\GNU Octave\\Octave-6.2.0\\mingw64\\bin\\octave-cli.exe')
import oct2py
out = oct2py.Oct2Py()
out.source('main.m')
```

it runs my .m file and shows the results also but after that I receive following error.

```
error: 'sentinel' undefined near line 99, column 99
error: called from
    _pyeval at line 99 column 10
```

whats going wrong here?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. It was resolved when I got rid of all `clear all` and `close` statements. Although I suspect `clear` to be the culprit.

This seems to be a known problem https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py/issues/185, which is your own post. Ah well ;)

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to close this thread here, Yes "clear" is the real culprit. xd

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py/issues/185
Here is the link regarding this thread. It's all due to "clear".

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.